# how to batch read_csv() of pandas module in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge many .txt files by using python pandas module.
code showed below:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
root='D:\daymet'
newfile=pd.DataFrame()            #all txt data will append on this variable
for file in os.listdir(root):
    if 'txt' in file:          
        pathname=os.path.join(root,file)    #file path
    temp=pd.read_csv(pathname)                # read csv
    newfile.append(temp,ignore_index=True)      #append
newfile.to_csv('D:\\merge.csv')                 #save as a newfile
```

### report error below:

```
EmptyDataError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-4282b0cc482a> in <module>()
      6     if 'txt' in file:
      7         pathname=os.path.join(root,file)
----> 8     temp=pd.read_csv(pathname)
      9     newfile.append(temp,ignore_index=True)
     10 newfile.to_csv('D:\\merge.csv')
```

.........

```
pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas\parser.c:6162)()

EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Comment: You either have a problem with the `pathname` or the file itself is duff, have you done any debugging here? For instance does it fail on the first file or a specific file? add code to pring the pathname to make sure it's valid

Comment: I tried print pathname. it is all fine.maybe the sytax of read_csv() contain a fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have missed tabs in 8 and 9 lines(You got file without 'txt' and try to open it without defining path).

```
import os
import pandas as pd
root='D:\daymet'
newfile=pd.DataFrame()            #all txt data will append on this variable
for file in os.listdir(root):
    if 'txt' in file:          
        pathname=os.path.join(root,file)  #file path <--add additional tab here
        temp=pd.read_csv(pathname)  # read csv <--add additional tab here
        newfile.append(temp,ignore_index=True)      #append
newfile.to_csv('D:\\merge.csv')                 #save as a newfile
```